# What is the difference between “You’ve made X?” and “Have you made X?”

Tags: differences, questions

My name is Micheal Gignac. I am new here. English is my native language, and I know a little bit of French. That is part and parcel of being a Canadian, you see.

I probably should explain the context surrounding my question. I found a game (or more accurately, interactive movie) titled “Cyberswine” on YouTube. It seems that it is an adaptation of an Australian short comic book series.

The game takes place in CyberCity in the year 2070. The protagonist is a Cyberswine, a cyborg who has a combination of a pig’s brain and a human brain as well as mechanical parts. He is brought in as a secret weapon for the police department. In case you are wondering, the premise has elements of “RoboCop” mixed in it, but the story plays out differently from that.

Cyberswine has four computer chips implanted into his system: the first one for combat, the second one for logic, the third one for public relations and the last one for emotion control. Early on, it becomes clear that two sinister characters have Cyberswine under surveillance. They are Vice-President Bryce Gets and the Scientist. Bryce basically sees life as one big chess game, and the conversation between him and his minion is as follows.

> **Vice-President Bryce Gets**: Good. The pawns are now in place. `You’ve made the modifications to his personality chips?`
>
> **The Scientist**: Yes, sir. As you ordered.
>
> **Vice-President Bryce Gets**: Good. Let the game begin!

I apologize for the long explanation, but I wanted to make the context surrounding the above conversation very clear. If I changed “You’ve made the modifications to his personality chips?” into “Have you made the modifications to his personality chips?”, would you detect any difference? If so, what is it?

It feels strange, doesn’t it? I’m a native speaker of English, and I’m asking a question about it!

Comment: In the particular context you provide, the two questions are equivalent. But I can imagine different circumstances where they wouldn't be. For example, if V.P. Bryce was curious about what TS had made, as opposed to getting a progress report.

Comment: The difference is in the subtext.  The statement as a question alludes to the fact that this was an order and the expectation is that it has been done.  The straight question is just that- a question.

Comment: @Jim: Oh, okay. I knew that there was a difference in nuance, but I couldn't figure out what it was. I think that you pinpointed that difference.